# Call Any inside Expression and pass the delegate

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, expression

I have a scenario here where I need to hit a dynamic query using linq (with nhibernate). The final query should look like this:

```
long[] values = { ... };

var result = Queryable<Entity>.Where(x => x.Documents.Any(d => values.Contains(d.Id)))
                              .ToList();
```

The generic `Entity` and the property `Documents` can change and it will be defined by some user configurations. The type of collection `Documents` is `ICollection<T>` where `T` is `Document` type. I am trying to create an `Expression` tree to define these statements dynamically but I am getting some issues. Look the code and comments bellow of what I have tried.

I have create this function to return the delagate I want to use inside the `Any` method:

```
    public static Func<T, bool> GetFunc<T>(long[] values)
        where T : Entity
    {
        return x => values.Contains(x.Id);
    }
```

And I am using the Expression class to make the expression like this (see code and comments):

```
// define my parameter of expression
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

// I get an array of IDs (long) as argument and transform it on an Expression
var valuesExpression = Expression.Constant(values);

// define the access to my collection property. propertyFilter is propertyinfo for the `Documents` of the sample above.
// I get an expression to represent: x.Documents
var collectionPropertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyFilter);

// get the T generic type of the ICollection<T> from propertyFilter. I get the `Documents` of sample above.
var entityFilterType = propertyFilter.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

// get the definition of `Any` extension method from `Enumerable` class to make the expression
var anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                                                      .First(x => x.Name == "Any" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                                                      .MakeGenericMethod(entityFilterType);

// get a methodBase for GetFunc to get the delagete to use inside the Any
// using the `Document` generic type
var collectionBody = typeof(LookUpHelper).GetMethod("GetFunc", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                                                             .MakeGenericMethod(entityFilterType);

// call the any passing the collection I need and convert it to a Delegate
// I get something like: x => values.Contains(x.Id) ... where x if the `Document`
var func = (Delegate)collectionBody.Invoke(null, new object[] { values });

// get the func as an expression .. maybe the problem is here
var funcExpression = Expression.Constant(func);

// call the any passing the collection and my delagate as arguments
var f = Expression.Call(anyMethod, collectionPropertyExpression, funcExpression);

// I already have an expression and concatenate it using `AndAlso` operator.
body = Expression.AndAlso(body, f);

// finally, I built up to lambda expression and apply it on my queryable
var filterExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);

var result = Queryable.Where(filterExpression).ToList();
```

It executes until the query be executed by `ToList` method. I am getting the following error:

> Could not parse expression
>   'x.Documents.Any(value(System.Func`2[Project.Document,System.Boolean]))':
>   The object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' cannot
>   be converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'. If
>   you tried to pass a delegate instead of a LambdaExpression, this is
>   not supported because delegates are not parsable expressions.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Someone can help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `Func` where an `Expression<Func>` is expected.  The former is a delegate and the latter is an expression.

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetFunc<T>(long[] values)
      where T : Entity
{
    return x => values.Contains(x.Id);
}
```

Now you forego needing to build the expression manually with your expression helper class since you already have the expression.

Comment: I have fix it and not it is working as expected. I was confusing about Func and Expression, I was blind and looking how to convert this Func to Expression and I didn't even think to change this non-dynamic method. Thank you David.

Comment: It's an easy trap to fall into. Happy to help!